# What are elipsoid parameters of SoilGrids?

Tags: coordinate-system, ellipsoid, soilgrids

For point sampling in R I need information of the underlying ellipsoid parameters of the database Soilgrids, because they seem to be different from other layers I am using.

I couldn't find any information in [this paper](https://storage.googleapis.com/plos-corpus-prod/10.1371/journal.pone.0105992/1/pone.0105992.pdf?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=wombat-sa%40plos-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20211018%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20211018T155343Z&X-Goog-Expires=86400&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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) on [the website](https://soilgrids.org/).

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange.com! It would be useful to provide a more detailed description about the problem you encounter in order to receive a good answer.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about its characteristics may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The SRS is detailed in the [SoilGrids FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_use_the_Homolosine_projection):

> The actual Spatial Reference System (SRS) of the SoilGrids maps is composed by the Homolosine projection applied to the WGS84 datum. [...]
>
> The verbose Well Known Text (WKT) version of this SRS is:
>
> ````
> PROJCS["Homolosine", 
>     GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
>         DATUM["WGS_1984", 
>             SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563, 
>                 AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],     AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
>         PRIMEM["Greenwich",0, 
>             AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
>         UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433, 
>             AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]], 
>         AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
>     PROJECTION["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine"], 
>     UNIT["Meter",1]]```
> ````

Note that a [more recent realisation](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/wgs84) of the WGS84 datum series was adopted by the NGA earlier this year.